# Get split times, Google Maps API, directions

Tags: api, google-maps, direction

I have been investigated how to and if it is possible to get split times for every 5 mile from the Google Maps API, regarding direction (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-panel)

Example:
You want to drive from Chicago to St Louis. From Google Maps API I get an array of whitch time the user (driver) would be on the route after each 5 mile. It could be in minutes.

```
array[] = {35, 60, 82, 101}
```

I haven't found anything about this in the documentation neither when Im googling. Does somebody have clue on how to solve this? (Sorry for my english, not my first language)

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong you are asking about the steps parameter which is returned by the [Google Direction API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/) when the user enters the origin and the destination location in the text boxes.

Now this steps parameter return an array of steps for a certain route. That step consist of distance as well as time for that particular step in that route. Please refer to this link for additional detail.

The JSON format returned by steps array looks like the following example. Although it is different than what you have came across in the question, which I was not able to find too.

```
"steps": [ {
        "travel_mode": "DRIVING",
        "start_location": {
          "lat": 41.8507300,
          "lng": -87.6512600
        },
        "end_location": {
          "lat": 41.8525800,
          "lng": -87.6514100
        },
        "polyline": {
          "points": "a~l~Fjk~uOwHJy@P"
        },
        "duration": {
          "value": 19,
          "text": "1 min"
        },
        "html_instructions": "Head \u003cb\u003enorth\u003c/b\u003e on \u003cb\u003eS Morgan St\u003c/b\u003e toward \u003cb\u003eW Cermak Rd\u003c/b\u003e",
        "distance": {
          "value": 207,
          "text": "0.1 mi"
        }
```